# RT patch is freezing

Tags: raspbian, kernel, real-time, crash

I have patched PREEMPT-RT for Raspbian Linux kernel. It works fine for normal operations (web browsing or short time programs) the following is the output of `uname -a` of my Rapsberry Pi 2 after patching

[image: Screenshot of uname -a output]

My problem is this systems is freezing for some code that I am running. I tried to make a simple code to calculate how long the Raspberry Pi 2 can stay without freezing.  I used the following code

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/Scripts/running_time

export start_time=$(date +'%Y/%m/%d___%H:%M:%S') 
printf $start_time > up_time

while true
do

printf 'start time %s \n end at %s' $start_time, $(date +'%Y/%m/%d___%H:%M:%S') > up_time
sleep 1

done
```

What I got is it freezes after about 4 hours. I have other code and it freezes after 1 hour and sometimes after 10 minutes.

I have monitored system performance remotely using ssh with htop, the following is observed at last moment before freezing:

```
RAM consumption: total memory consumption about 120 M

running script load: only 6 M
```

So for me:

- Raspbian without the PREEMPT-RT patch is working without freezing.
- Raspbian with the PREEMPT-RT patch without any running applications is working without freezing.
- Raspbian with the PREEMPT-RT patch running applications is freezing.

I hope someone has suggestions or explanations for solving this issue please.

---

UPDATE: 16.10.2016

I have worked on solving this problem for almost 1 year. Simply I wasn't able to solve it. But I will try to describe what actions I had taken maybe I can shorten sometime for people who are suffering from the same problem:

1. for applying the PREEMPT-RT patch, please use this link http://www.frank-durr.de/?p=203 as it is the best resource explaining how to apply the PRREMPT-RT.
2. you are free to execute `sudo apt-get update`. it doesn't matter.
3. to predict if your linux going to freeze or not, use ltp test suite

   ```
   wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/ltp/ltp-full-20150420.tar.bz2
   ```

   there you can build realtime test cases:

   ```
   tar xvf ltp-full-20150420.tar.bz2
   cd ltp-full-20150420
   ./configure --with-realtime-testsuite
   cd testcases/realtime
   make
   ```

   then execute a test called pthread_kill_latency (`sudo ./run.sh -t func/pthread_kill_latency -l 25`)
   usually the linux will freeze in first 5 running.
4. When freezing, switch off your power then switch it on again, open log message `nano /var/log/syslog` maybe you can find a clue what happend before freezing immediately.

That is all my conclusion. I had to stop searching for that problem. If someone found a solution, I will be grateful if he/she shares with us here.

Answer (score 3):

If somebody finds this via search engines:

Re-compiling anything won't help at all, don't waste your time on that.

It's simply an issue with the Kernel and/or the Raspberry Pi firmware.

See here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=159170

Comment: According to that link, [down in that thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=159170#p1092964), this problem was related to "FIQ exception handler that the driver of the Synopsis DWC host USB controller is using by default" and is **now resolved**. The original patch is introduced [here](https://www.osadl.org/Single-View.111+M5c03315dc57.0.html), and a more recent rebased version is [here](https://github.com/fedberry/kernel/blob/master/usb-dwc_otg-fix-system-lockup-when-interrupts-are-threaded.patch). Still not in the main RPi kernel as of today.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple =) The apps that causing a freeze condition you're experiencing are installed from binary distributions(packages via `apt-get`, binary downloads, etc) - recompile all the stuff with your kernel headers and sources **to properly utilize your RT patch in your software**. This will stop this kind of truble : it also happens by the same mechanism in case of compatibility implications between kernel/modules, kernel/software etc. If you will still have such problems after a FULL rebuild - write here so I'll be able to help you further

Comment: Thanks Alexey for your input.  I would like to add note that I ran the script that I mentioned before. I ran this script only with no other applications and I got this freezing situation. In addition that this script doesn't need any building procedures, it is just writing the time in a file. Do u think that I miss any building here?

Comment: @moibrahim rebuild a GCC and **all** the libraries for GCC(mpfr,gmp,mpc,cloog,isl), rebuild binutils, bash and coreutils(for *date* command), let's take a look what it will bring us

Comment: i tried this before and still freezing. I can send u kernel file if u want to check at ur side

Comment: @moibrahim so you have recompiled all the things on your RPi - and it still freezes?!

Comment: yes it freezes and giving no response, I have to unplug the power if i want to restart the system

Comment: @moibrahim have you tried the last kernel from kernel.org Git?

Comment: I used kernel provided in Raspberry Pi website. That is because they are providing kernel already ported to used processor(bcm2836). I don't like to use kernel from kernel.org because it is not ported, it needs alot of effort then to port then to apply the patch.

Comment: @moibrahim I used kernel.org latest stable from Git - and they've adopted all the patches already, they have even an autoconfig for bcm CPU's, so it's totally OK to use it. I'm building my Linux Distro for Raspberries and some other ARM board now, and RT patch will be shipped too, if you want to test it as soon as it will be available - let's keep in touch?

Comment: @ Alexey sorry for late reply. Actually I used this link to get the kernel https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux so i don't know if u mean other link. I worked with version 4.1.15 and applied preempt-rt patch 4.1.13 (this version was the available one) . I like ofcourse to keep in touch for solving this issue please

Comment: I was able to use [the official stable](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git) kernel, try to get it from there. Also there's a sunxi version on kernel.org that is for ARM special needs. But I felt no problem using a stable mainline.